# How to get regex to return string (not a regex object)?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've read the regex documentation, but it is very confusing for a beginner programmer like me. So my last resort is to post here.

```
# Tivo Notifier
import os, re

WATCH_DIR = "D:/tivo"
TO_FIND = [".*big.brother.uk.s15.*", ".*mock.the.week.*", ".*family.guy.*"]

# open history log file
history = open("history.txt", "w+")

# get downloaded files
files = os.listdir(WATCH_DIR)

# compare each file to regex patterns
for pattern in TO_FIND:
    regex =  re.compile(pattern)
    match = [m.group(0) for file in files for m in [regex.search(file)] if m]

    for filename in match:
        if filename not in history.read():      # if a new match is found
            print "new:", filename              # display new match file name
            history.write(filename)             # add file name to history file
history.close()
```

The problem here is that it writes a ton of garbage to the history file:
http://pastebin.com/3C5iVbU7

I'm assuming this is because `filename` is not a string, and is probably a kind of regex object. I cannot see in the documentation how to return a string.

**I would like to add only the file name to the history file, not the garbage text that is actually added from this script.**

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I don't think `history.read()` returns a list, it returns a single string. So `filename not in history.read()` won't work. You need `history.read().split('\n')`.

Comment: Also, reading the whole history file each time through the loop is very inefficient. Read it once at the beginning.

Comment: You need to write a newline after each filename in the history file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more straightforward way that uses [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob) instead of regular expressions.
It also uses [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to maintain history and new files.

```
import os, glob

WATCH_DIR = 'D:/tivo'
TO_FIND = ['*big.brother.uk.s15*', '*mock.the.week*', '*family.guy*']

history = set(open('history.txt').read().splitlines())

new_files = set()
for pattern in TO_FIND:
        files = glob.glob(os.path.join(WATCH_DIR, pattern))
        # optionally strip directories from file names
        files = [os.path.basename(f) for f in files]
        new_files.update(files)

new_files = new_files.difference(history)
for f in sorted(new_files):
        print "new: %s" % f

history.update(new_files)
open('history.txt', 'w').write('%s\n' % '\n'.join(sorted(history)))
```